# what is the proper way to set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES in cmake file to use different GPU core

Tags: cmake, cuda, gpu

I have a project that uses cmake for compilation and unittest afterwards. The standard procedure for it is

`cmake .. -DUSE_CUDA=ON ; make ; make test ARGS="-j 10"`

The problem is that during the `make test` phase, I have 4 GPUs on my server and only one GPU is used. I can see it through `nvidia-smi` command. I'm wondering if there is a method to set in Cmakefiles to change the GPU being used and eventually utilize all GPUs.

Here is the unit test code that will execute all the test cases. I tried to force it on GPU 1 by setting environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to 1. However the code still runs on GPU core 0.

```
function(py_test TARGET_NAME)
  set(options "")
  set(oneValueArgs "")
  set(multiValueArgs SRCS DEPS ARGS ENVS)
  set(ENV{CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES} 1)
  cmake_parse_arguments(py_test "${options}" "${oneValueArgs}" "${multiValueArgs}" ${ARGN})
  get_filename_component(work_dir ${py_test_SRCS} DIRECTORY)
  add_test(NAME ${TARGET_NAME}
           COMMAND ${COVERAGE_EXECUTABLE} run --parallel-mode --source=test_module "${py_test_SRCS}" ${py_test_ARGS}
           WORKING_DIRECTORY ${work_dir})
endfunction()

function(add_files)
  set(options "")
  set(oneValueArgs "")
  set(multiValueArgs SRCS)
  cmake_parse_arguments(add_files "${options}" "${oneValueArgs}" "${multiValueArgs}" ${ARGN})
  foreach(test_file ${add_files_SRCS})
    get_filename_component(test ${test_file} NAME_WE)
    get_filename_component(test_abs ${test_file} ABSOLUTE)
    message(STATUS "test_file:${test_file}")
    py_test(${test} SRCS ${test_abs})
  endforeach()
endfunction()

# Put cases cost more time before the less ones 

set(COVERAGE_EXECUTABLE /usr/local/bin/coverage-3.6)

# unit test
file(GLOB UNIT_TEST unit_test_folder/test_*.py)
add_files(SRCS ${UNIT_TEST})
```

I've tried to set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` in the command terminal before running `cmake test` and it worked.

Also, do I have to preassign the tests to different dedicated GPU or can they be dynamically assigned.

Comment: GPU? CMake doesn't even care that much about the CPU. Even `make` would be quite unlikely to use the GPU itself. Go read the actual test code. And obviously, if there's a problem you can't solve with that code, post that code. We can't debug unseen code.

Comment: @MSalters I've posted the test code here and updated my question. Sorry that I did not know about cmake much.

Comment: I've tried to see the environment setting by `message(STATUS CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES $ENV{CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES})` and found the env variable is set correctly but not working.

Comment: I've also tried to set it in add_test function by the following code: `add_test(NAME ${TARGET_NAME}
           COMMAND CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 ${COVERAGE_EXECUTABLE} run --parallel-mode --source=horizon_nn "${py_test_SRCS}" ${py_test_ARGS}
           WORKING_DIRECTORY ${work_dir})` and got error: `Could not find executable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1`

Comment: execute command `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 make test ARGS="-j 10"` worked for me, but I'm wondering if I could set it inside cmakelist file.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to preassign tests to different GPUs with code like this:

```
function(py_test TARGET_NAME) 
  set(options "")
  set(oneValueArgs "")
  set(multiValueArgs SRCS DEPS ARGS ENVS)
  MATH(EXPR CUDA_ID "(${CUDA_ID}+1)%4")
  set(CUDA_ID ${CUDA_ID} PARENT_SCOPE)
  cmake_parse_arguments(py_test "${options}" "${oneValueArgs}" "${multiValueArgs}" ${ARGN})
  get_filename_component(work_dir ${py_test_SRCS} DIRECTORY)
  add_test(NAME ${TARGET_NAME}
           COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=${CUDA_ID} ${COVERAGE_EXECUTABLE} run --parallel-mode --source=horizon_nn "${py_test_SRCS}" ${py_test_ARGS} 
           WORKING_DIRECTORY ${work_dir})
  message(STATUS CUDA_ID ${CUDA_ID})
endfunction()

set(CUDA_ID 0)
```

But still, dynamic assign is still not achievable since all these tests are preassigned at `cmake` phase